# Angular: how to configure mat-tree-select-input

Tags: css, angular, drop-down-menu, tree

I am using the module mat-tree-select-input from
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mat-tree-select-input, and find it is very convenient to use if I want to build a tree like dropdown menu.
However, I am having difficulty to change its appearance such as width, borderless and color.

```
<ngx-mat-tree-select-input-ngmodel class="mat-tree-select"
  (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged()"
  [(select)]="value"
  [options]="tree_data"
  [canSelectParentNode]="false">
</ngx-mat-tree-select-input-ngmodel>
```

The TS file:

```
import { TreeData } from 'mat-tree-select-input';
...
tree_data: TreeData[] = [
    {
      name: 'Electronics',
      value: 'Electronics',
      children: [
        {
          name: 'Phones',
          value: 'Phones',
          children: [
            {
              name: 'Iphones',
              value: 'Iphones', 
              children: []
              
            } 
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
   
    {
      name: 'Web Development',
      value: 'Web Development',
      children: [
        {
          name: 'Frontend Development',
          value: 'Frontend Development',
          children: [
            {
              name: 'Angular',
              value: 'Angular',
              children: []

              
            },
            {
              name: 'React',
              value: 'React',
              children: []

              
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
  ]

onSelectionChanged() {}
```

I have tried add "width" or in the style file:

```
.mat-tree-select {
  max-width: 400px !important;
  width: 100%;
  color: #255002;
}
```

None of these works. Is there anyone familiar with its use?

Comment: View encapsulation is causing your style to not be applied. https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep
Use `:host ::ng-deep .mat-tree-select` in the parent component stylesheet

Comment: Thank you. This is promising, but I still don't see improvement. What is still missing? I added some data so this can be easily replicated.